# Rails Asset Pipeline: image-url not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

**Context**

Rails 4.

**Problem**

I know this has been asked many times before, but I can't get the following line of CSS to work:

```
background: image-url("home/smiling.jpg");
```

My file is in the right place, name is good. the line `background-color: red;` DOES work.

**Attempts at a solution**

SO searches.

i've tried `rake assets:precompile`. Also `rake assets:clean`

No luck so far.

Comment: app/assets/images/home/smiling.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

1. Add a slash before home: `"/home/smiling.jpg"`
2. Use `background-image: url` instead of 'background: image-url'.

`background-image: url("home/smiling.jpg");`

That markup works for me in Rails 4.1.